# pass type to decode json in haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, aeson

I think I'm going about this problem in a fundamentally incorrect way, but I'm not sure how to make an elegant solution in Haskell.

I would like to write a function which parses a string of JSON into some Haskell type. However, I don't know how to pass the type into my function (which I don't think I can do).

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
data Foo = Foo { _a :: String } deriving (Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)
data Bar = Bar { _b :: String } deriving (Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)

parseSomething :: (FromJSON a) => a -> Maybe a
parseSomething a = (decode "..some json string...") :: Maybe a
```

Is this possible, or am I thinking about the problem incorrectly?

At the moment, I receive a type deduction error:

```
    • Could not deduce (FromJSON a1) arising from a use of ‘decode’
      from the context: FromJSON a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   foo :: forall a. FromJSON a => a -> Maybe a
        at src/Plumbing/Types.hs:60:1-35
      Possible fix:
        add (FromJSON a1) to the context of
          an expression type signature:
            forall a1. Maybe a1
    • In the expression: decode "{\"_a\":\"foo\"}" :: (Maybe a)
      In an equation for ‘foo’:
          foo a = decode "{\"_a\":\"foo\"}" :: (Maybe a)
   |
61 | foo a = decode "{\"_a\":\"foo\"}" :: (Maybe a)
```

Comment: Well you can use parenthesis here `myFoo (parseSomething Foo)`, but nevertheless, why not use a type hint?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I believe I had a typo, or perhaps I'm not understanding your suggestion.

Comment: Why do you use an `a` here, why not use `myFoo = decode "... some json string ..." :: Maybe Foo`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In this case, I want a function which doesn't need to know about `Foo`s. I would like to be able to call `parseSomething Bar` or `parseSomething Foo`, so that I can abstract away the actual type which the json is begin mapped to.

Comment: Why not just write `parseSomething :: FromJSON a => Maybe a`, i.e. with no argument, and then use `parseSomething :: Maybe Foo` or `parseSomething :: Maybe Bar` (...or let type inference work out the right one to pick) at the use site?

Comment: @genuinequestion You can't call `parseSomething Bar` because `Bar` is not a value but a type.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [type applications](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications) extension for this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

data Foo = Foo { _a :: String } deriving (Show, Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)
data Bar = Bar { _b :: String } deriving (Show, Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)

parseSomething :: (FromJSON a) => Maybe a
parseSomething = decode "{ \"_a\": \"Hello\" }"

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show (foo, bar)
  where
    foo = parseSomething @Foo
    bar = parseSomething @Bar
```

but honestly I see zero benefit of being able to write

```
foo = parseSomething @Foo
bar = parseSomething @Bar
```

over

```
foo = parseSomething :: Maybe Foo
bar = parseSomething :: Maybe Bar
```